# python opencv cv2.findContours cannot match square within image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image as following:

[image]

Hand write within the square is random changed, so, sometimes looks like:

[image]

I wanna match the square by the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
import cv2
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

img = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

tmpimage,contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.05*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==5:
        print "pentagon"
        #cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,255,2)
    elif len(approx)==3:
        print "triangle"
        #cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2)
    elif len(approx)==4:
        print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),2)
    elif len(approx) == 9:
        print "half-circle"
        #cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,255,0),2)
    elif len(approx) > 15:
        print "circle"
        #cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,255),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imwrite('tmp.png',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following:

[image]

So, failed to get the square.

I also changed findContours and approxPolyDP params but all failed to get the center square.

I also tried template matching, code snippet:

```
cv2.matchTemplate(an_origin_part,an_template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

an_template image here:

[image]

And I set threshold to 0.55 to match the template.

Well, problem is, there is random hand write within the target squere, so, the template matching sometimes doesn't work anymore.

Env:

Python: 2.7.10

Opencv: 3.2.0

Any suggestion for matching the square is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue.

The reason I found is that the square is removed when first threshold.

So, mainly changed the following two lines:

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Note the threshold and white-black reverse.

```
tmpimage,contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Note that I fetch the external contour.

With above , I got the square :-)